# How to send a value from a form to a Javascript function in cshtml?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently trying to call a javascript function by a form inside cshtml file. There would be a textbox in the form that receive string from the user and 'Send' button which send the string to the javascript function.

Script for the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchStreet", "CustomerInformation", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="CustId" value="@ViewBag.CustId" />
    <input type="hidden" name="AddressId" value="@ViewBag.AddressId" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="street">Street Name</label>
        @Html.TextBox("street", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="form-control btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
```

How to send the string to the specific Javascript function?
Thanks.

Comment: add a "onclick" method to button, in that method get that textbox value using getElementById("id goes here")

Answer (score 2):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchStreet", "CustomerInformation", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="CustId" value="@ViewBag.CustId" />
    <input type="hidden" name="AddressId" value="@ViewBag.AddressId" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="street">Street Name</label>
        @Html.TextBox("street", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>
        <input type="submit" onclick="sendValue();" value="Send" class="form-control btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
function sendValue(){
    var element = document.getElementById(street);
    //Get value by element.value, rest you know what to do
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try :D

Answer (score 1):

Add a onclick on send button.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label></label>
        <input type="button" onclick="checkText();" value="Send" class="form-control btn btn-default" />
    </div>
```

In javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkText(){
  var number=document.getElementById("street").value;
  //DO you stuff here
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to send textbox value to javascript function when button will get click,
so i have following scenario try it. it may help you.

-- Script Section--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DemoFunction()
{
 var stringValue1=$('#street').val(); --> if you use jQuery

 var stringValue2=document.getElementById("street").value; --> if you use 
 only javascript
 alert(stringValue1);
 alert(stringValue2);
}
</script>
```

-- View Section --

```
  -- add 'onclick="return DemoFunction()' this to your button

  ex:-  
  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="form-control btn btn-default" 
onclick="return DemoFunction()" />
```